# jQuery working on PC but not on WAMP or Shared Server

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, google-maps

I don't know why but I have a piece of code which works on my system but is not working on WAMP or Shared server.

Below is my piece of code :-

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      (function($) {

        $.ajax({
          url:"select2.json",
          type:"GET",
          dataType:"json",
          success:function(data){

            var selectedDepartment, selectedSubproj;

            $.fn.changeType = function() {

              var options_projname = '<option>Select<\/option>';
              $.each(data, function(i, d) {
                options_projname += '<option value="' + d.projname + '">' + d.projname + '<\/option>';
              });
              $("select#projname", this).html(options_projname);

              $("select#projname").change(function() {
                var index = $(this).get(0).selectedIndex;

                var d = data[index - 1]; // -1 because index 0 is for empty 'Select' option
                selectedDepartment = d;
                var options = '';
                if (index > 0) {
                  options += '<option>Select<\/option>';
                  $.each(d.subproj, function(i, j) {
                    options += '<option value="' + j.title + '">' + j.title + '<\/option>';
                  });
                } else {
                  options += '<option>Select<\/option>';
                }
                $("select#subproj").html(options);
              });
              $("select#subproj").change(function() {
                var index = $(this).get(0).selectedIndex;
                selectedSubproj = selectedDepartment.subproj[index -1];
                var options = '';
                if (index > 0) {
                  $.each(selectedSubproj.unit, function(i, b) {
                    //options += '<option value="' + b.name + '">' + b.name + '<\/option>';
                    options += '<input type="checkbox" name="' + b.name + '" value="' + b.name + '">' + b.name + '<br/>';
                  });
                } else {
                  options += '<option>Select<\/option>';
                }
                $("#unit").html(options);
              });
            };


          }
        });
      })(jQuery);

      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("form#search").changeType();
      });
    </script>

    <form id="search" action="" name="search">
      <select name="projname" id="projname">
        <option>Select</option>
      </select>

      <select name="subproj" id="subproj">
        <option>Select</option>
      </select>

      <div name="unit" id="unit">

      </div>

    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am getting the following error when I run in WAMP or Shared Server.
http://s8.postimg.org/vj19w76v9/error.png
But it runs fine if I run it like a normal html file on my pc.
My JSON is also rendering very well so I know that there is no issue with it.

I tried clearing cache and all the good stuff but its eating my brain off...

Would be glad if someone could help.

Thanks in advance... Cheers...

Comment: Looks like the issue is with the `changeType` plugin. It is not registering when it is run on a server!

Comment: You are defining the changeType plugin inside your ajaxs success callback. It must be a race condition probably thats why in your local env works because there is no delay in the ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are defining your `changeType` plugin in your `success` callback of the ajax call. Thus, at the time the document is ready, when you call that plugin, it will be undefined. You will need to define the plugin first and think of a way to pass the `data` variable you get from the ajax call by parameter. I believe something rough like this should work:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.changeType = function (data) {
        var selectedDepartment, selectedSubproj;
        var options_projname = '<option>Select<\/option>';
        $.each(data, function (i, d) {
            options_projname += '<option value="' + d.projname + '">' + d.projname + '<\/option>';
        });
        $("select#projname", this).html(options_projname);

        $("select#projname").change(function () {
            var index = $(this).get(0).selectedIndex;

            var d = data[index - 1]; // -1 because index 0 is for empty 'Select' option
            selectedDepartment = d;
            var options = '';
            if (index > 0) {
                options += '<option>Select<\/option>';
                $.each(d.subproj, function (i, j) {
                    options += '<option value="' + j.title + '">' + j.title + '<\/option>';
                });
            } else {
                options += '<option>Select<\/option>';
            }
            $("select#subproj").html(options);
        });
        $("select#subproj").change(function () {
            var index = $(this).get(0).selectedIndex;
            selectedSubproj = selectedDepartment.subproj[index - 1];
            var options = '';
            if (index > 0) {
                $.each(selectedSubproj.unit, function (i, b) {
                    //options += '<option value="' + b.name + '">' + b.name + '<\/option>';
                    options += '<input type="checkbox" name="' + b.name + '" value="' + b.name + '">' + b.name + '<br/>';
                });
            } else {
                options += '<option>Select<\/option>';
            }
            $("#unit").html(options);
        });
    };


})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "select2.json",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $("form#search").changeType(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks dude... Your solution worked with some minor tweaks... I will post the full working code soon... Cheers...